# Cartopy, test if a geodetic line between two points is always in water

Tags: python, cartopy

I have a set of points in the Mediterranean Sea. I know how to compute the geodesic distance among them, and I need to build a Minumum spanning tree among them.

But, since there are several islands in the sea, I'd like to exclude the edges (among set of points) such that, the geodesic that connect them goes through one island.

I do not know if Cartopy provide some function to do this or if there are other libraries in Python that are able to solve the problem

Comment: I think this example in the cartopy gallery is relevant https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/hurricane_katrina.html#sphx-glr-gallery-hurricane-katrina-py  This page gives more information on loading shapefiles https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/tutorials/using_the_shapereader.html#helper-functions-for-shapefile-acquisition

Comment: thanks. it seems a good link. perfect.

Comment: @AntonioCaruso would you mind posting an example? It might even find its way into the cartopy gallery (with permission).